# Secuenciar una fecha epoch

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

El problema es el siguiente, despues de aplicar esta query:

```sql
SELECT 
  my_date, 
  round(
    (
      cast(
        sys_extract_utc(
          cast('my_date' AS TIMESTAMP)
        ) AS DATE
      ) - to_date(
        '01-01-1970', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24MISS'
      )
    ) 2460 * 60
  ) AS pol_timestamp 
FROM 
  my_table
```

| 'my_date' | epoch |
| --- | --- |
| 25-OCT-22 | 1666648800 |
| 25-OCT-22 | 1666648800 |

Lo que queremos, es que a pesar de que los segundos no entren, o entran a 00, de alguna manera forcemos eso y que lo veamos de manera secuenciada.

Gracias

Comment: Pon un ejemplo con el resultado que deseas obtener

Comment: Pues que el resultado del epoch venga separado cada 5 s, es decir:
1666648805, 1666648810